# html code with css not working in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am building an HTML signature for our company. Previously, I used a sliced photo, but because I want to combine text and images, I'd like to do entirely HTML (table, links, text, image, etc.)

Looks great on edit plus, looks great when I open the chrome file of the finished product, but actually getting it into outlook is a problem.  In Outlook, everything is squished into one columns, rather than my table layout.

I've tried copying and pasting directly into the Outlook box, I've tried creating a new signature, and editing the document with my code.

```html
<style>
    Details {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: "Arial";
        color: #39262d;
    }
    Person {
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: "Arial";
        color: #749b53;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    Job {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: "Arial";
        color: #39262d;
        font-weight: bold;  
    }
    deta {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: "Arial";
        color: #39262d;
    }
</style>


<table style="width: 379px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 116px;">
                <a href="https://www.grapaes.com" target="_blank"> <img style="width: 100px; height: auto; border: 0;" src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Grapa_Logo%20TM10pt%20-%20CLEAR.png? 
                    _t=1561901957" alt="Logo" width="121" border="0" /></a>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 262px;">
                <p>
                    <Person>
                        <br />Person
                    </Person>
                    <br />
                    <Job>Job</Job>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <deta>CompanyName
                        <br />Phone:
                        <br />Mobile:
                    </deta>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 379px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <img style="width: 750px; height: 5px; border: 0;" src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Grapa%20line%20green%209%20pt.png? 
                _t=1562055131" alt="Line" width="121" border="0" />
            <td style="width: 3479px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Pictures and text are not properly aligne.d

Comment: Probably you have to make all styles `inline`... that's mean that you must remove all the `<style>` `</style>` and put them in each element. Like: `<deta style="font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial; color: #39262d;">`

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't sure what inline meant - I thought it referred to the seperate style sheet, as opposed to within the <style>  Thank you so much for explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@brooksreylt's answer is a great starting point but there are still a couple of things you don't need, such as the extra cell next to your green line. You also have mismatched widths that should really be addressed.

1. The green line at the very bottom has a width of 750px but then also an HTML attribute width of 121. Decide on one and make both the same. On top of this, the table wrapping this element is set as 379px to match the table above. This also conflicts with the image width.
2. You need to house the image inside of a table cell and then there is no need to set a width on that cell.

Here are the alterations I would make:

```html
<table style="width: 379px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 116px;"><a href="https://www.grapaes.com" 
        target="_blank"> <img style="width: 100px; height: auto; border: 0;" 
        src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Grapa_Logo%20TM10pt%20-%20CLEAR.png? 
        _t=1561901957" alt="Logo" width="121" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td style="width: 262px;">
                <span style="font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #749b53; font-weight: bold;">Person</span><br />
                <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #39262d; font-weight: bold;">Job</span><br /><br /> 
                <span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #39262d;">CompanyName<br />Phone:<br />Mobile:</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
                                    
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img style="width: 600px; border: 0;" 
            src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Grapa%20line%20green%209%20pt.png? 
            _t=1562055131" alt="Line" width="600" border="0" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! You've really explained the logic of this.

Answer (score 0):

@Roy is right, all styles must be inline styles when coding an email for outlook or any other client (Gmail, Yahoo, etc). Style tags are read by your browser during development. But, more often than not those styles are stripped out by the email client and your email will be left without styles. Inline styles are a way to get around this.

Below is your code reworked with inline styles. I also changed your custom tags to be span tags so they are standard HTML elements. I removed tags like Person, Job, etc. And I even removed paragraph tags. I did this because the margin and padding values will be different browser to browser and email client to email client. This will give you the best chance at having a standard layout for all platforms/email clients.

```
<table style="width: 379px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 116px;">
                <a href="https://www.grapaes.com" target="_blank"> 
                    <img style="width: 100px; height: auto; border: 0;" src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Grapa_Logo%20TM10pt%20-%20CLEAR.png? _t=1561901957" alt="Logo" width="121" border="0" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 262px;">
                <span style="font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #749b53; font-weight: bold;">Person</span><br />
                <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #39262d; font-weight: bold;">Job</span><br /><br /> 
                <span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #39262d;">CompanyName<br />Phone:<br />Mobile:</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 379px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img style="width: 750px; height: 5px; border: 0;" src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Grapa%20line%20green%209%20pt.png?_t=1562055131" alt="Line" width="121" border="0" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 3479px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - for the explanation as well.  I'm learning about this, and this is good info!